# 'site_index' variable in channel:categories has specific URL

Tags: categories, path

In the following code, I want `site_index` to continue to point to `http://blah.com/` but instead it points to something like `http://blah.com/category/catalog/downloads`:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="downloads" show_empty="no" style="linear"}
    <a href="{path='site_index'}/downloads">{category_name}</a>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

How do I prevent `channel:categories` from taking over the `site_index` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be best left not messing with that and using `{site_url}` instead.

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#site-url

Comment: Thanks, @Stephen. Only downside I've found to using `{site_url}` instead is that it doesn't automatically include the `/index.php?` in the URL, which my site's server currently requires. So if we ever remove the `/index.php?` we'll need to update this link.

Comment: If you need to, you can setup a snippet as `{site_url}/index.php?` and just call the snippet instead.